# onShouldStartLoadWithRequest automatically calling in iOS React Native on loading of any url in WebView, How to control it?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I'm implementing in App WebView for my App. I've to open some info pages and I've to get some data based on the click of any particular place(which contains a different type of data) in webview. But in iOS, while loading any URL *`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`* calling automatically which leads opening different URLs in the HTML content. But it is working as expected in Android.

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={["*"]}
  style={style}
  source={source}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={showsVerticalScrollIndicator}
  startInLoadingState={startInLoadingState}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={request => {
    return onLoadWebViewOnClick(request)
  }}
/>
```

in this handleUrlNavigation will handle the request of any click action, but it is automatically calling every time. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved it. It requires a platform check since iOS calls the function on load but android does not.

With this both on ios and android my webview loads with my HTML and when a user clicks a link inside the webview they are redirected to the native browser.

```
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
        const isExternalLink =
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? event.navigationType === 'click' : true;
        if (event.url.slice(0, 4) === 'http' && isExternalLink) {
          Linking.canOpenURL(event.url).then(supported => {
            if (supported) {
              Linking.openURL(event.url);
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was that I was getting for url: 'about:blank', so I added this (but you can add some other condition) :

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {
    return event.url === ‘about:blank’ ? event.navigationType === ‘click’ : true;
}}
```

And because I'm not using phones browser, and I regulate navigation through

onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {/*Your condition for navigation*/}}