# React-Native webview - unhandled promise about:blank in IOS

Tags: react-native, webview

The same website works absolute fine in android, however in iOS it seems to come up with this message:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:11): Error: Unable to open URL about:blank
```

I also seem to get this when the site URI is linking to URLs from a different domain.

I have tried adding:  `originWhitelist={['*']}`

Here is the Webview code:

```
<WebView
        style={styles.flexContainer}
        startInLoadingState
        renderLoading={() => 
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ffffff" styles={styles.loader}/>
          </View>
        }
        onMessage={event => {
          parseWebData(event.nativeEvent.data);
        }}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {  
          if (!event.url.startsWith(base)) {
              Linking.openURL(event.url)
              return false
          }
          return true
          }}
      originWhitelist = {['*']}
      source = {{ uri: base + uri }}
        />
```

Comment: Can you paste your webview code here..

Comment: @mainak - updated with the webview code, thanks

Comment: mentioned an answer below, try with that, its working/not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {  
          if (!event.url.startsWith(base)) {
              Linking.openURL(event.url)
              return false
          }
          return true
          }}
```

This was the problem.

iOS treats any URL load with this, whereas Android only fires this on clicking.

See this post for the explanation of the issue:
[onShouldStartLoadWithRequest automatically calling in iOS React Native on loading of any url in WebView, How to control it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493866/onshouldstartloadwithrequest-automatically-calling-in-ios-react-native-on-loadin)

Answer (score 0):

1st try this one

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: base + uri }}
  style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}
  useWebKit={true}
  startInLoadingState={false}
  javaScriptEnabled
  domStorageEnabled
/>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Just realised this could be causing an issue:onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {  
          if (!event.url.startsWith(base)) {
              Linking.openURL(event.url)
              return false
          }

Comment: @RobertOwen try with giving a style of height and width, it worked for me, updated my answer above