# React-Native-Webview getting iframes and mailto links working

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

How can I get both an iframe and mailto working together in a WebView?  I get each of them to work independently, but not together.

Case 1: IFrames will work with the following originWhitelist but mailto links will not.

<WebView
originWhitelist={['*']}
....
/>

Case 2: mailto links work with the following, but IFrames will not (error: can't open url: about:srcdoc)

<WebView
originWhitelist={['http://', 'https://', 'mailto://*', ]}
....
/>

If I try to add the wildcard to the working mailto case, iFrames will work as in case 1, mailto does not.

<WebView
originWhitelist={['http://', 'https://', 'mailto://', "" ]}
....
/>

How can I get both an iframe and mailto working together?

Please note: the iframe and mailto are separate. In other words, the mailto link is not within the iframe. It's on its own page.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using onShouldStartLoadWithRequest.  I got the idea from this post:

[onShouldStartLoadWithRequest automatically calling in iOS React Native on loading of any url in WebView, How to control it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493866/onshouldstartloadwithrequest-automatically-calling-in-ios-react-native-on-loadin)

Here's a working example should anyone else run into this issue.  You can swap out "mailto" for anything, make sure to adjust the slice though.  Also, test on a real device, this will fail on an emulator.

```
<WebView      
    originWhitelist={[ '*']}
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => { 
      if (event.url.slice(0, 6) === 'mailto') {
       
            Linking.openURL(event.url);
            return false
      }
      return true;
      }}
    source={{ uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com', }}
/>
```